# How do I press a key for one second in powershell script?

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script:

```
$i = 0
$delay = 1000
while($i -eq 0)
{
$myshell = New-Object -com "Wscript.Shell"
$myshell.sendkeys("q")
Start-Sleep -m $delay
}
```

It works but instead of sending a key only for a moment, I want to simulate pressing a key for a while, e.g. 1 second.

Comment: Send keys to what? Your code is doing what you told it to do. You have no timer to check, and you have set an infinite loop here (aka, don't do that's just bad practice and issue prone). So, WHy are you trying to send 1000 q's? You can do that without the loop, or you just trying to test a timer condition only and the number of key presses does not really matter?

Comment: Just to simulate pressing a key. The problem is the current code presses a key for a very short moment, I don't know like 0.00001 ms, and I want to press a key for like 1 second. Like literally you press a key and hold it for 1 second

Comment: OK, but as for this: ` Like literally you press a key and hold it for 1 second`, well that is not much different than the first part of my example. Yet, to truly get what you are after, means more work. You need a timer object.

Answer (score 5):

To send multiple keystrokes to whatever with sendkeys, you can just do this ( no real need for the WScript stuff):

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('q'*3)
# Results
<#
qqq
#>
```

If you are trying to do this against a time state, then you need to provide that. So, that means setting up a stopwatch.

> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+using+a+timer%27&t=h_&ia=web

An example of a timer with a form:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  Microsoft.VisualBasic,
                        PresentationCore,
                        PresentationFramework,
                        System.Drawing,
                        System.Windows.Forms,
                        WindowsBase,
                        WindowsFormsIntegration

$delay = 10
$Counter_Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$Counter_Form.Text = "Countdown Timer!"
$Counter_Form.Width = 450
$Counter_Form.Height = 200
$Counter_Label = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
$Counter_Label.AutoSize = $true 
$Counter_Form.Controls.Add($Counter_Label)
while ($delay -ge 0)
{
  $Counter_Form.Show()
  $Counter_Label.Text = "Seconds Remaining: $($delay)"
  start-sleep 1
  $delay -= 1
}
$Counter_Form.Close()
```

Using a timer object, a short example:

```
$Timer = New-Object system.diagnostics.stopwatch
$Timer.Start()
Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 1001
$Timer.Stop()
$timer
# Results
<#
IsRunning Elapsed          ElapsedMilliseconds ElapsedTicks
--------- -------          ------------------- ------------
    False 00:00:01.0055471                1005     10055471
#>
```

So, you end up going down the above, with your code.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Timer = New-Object system.diagnostics.stopwatch
$Timer.Start()
while ($Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds -le 1000)
{[System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('q')}
# Results
<#
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqq
#>
```

Using a delay/sleep

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Timer = New-Object system.diagnostics.stopwatch
$Timer.Start()
while ($Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds -le 1000)
{
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('q')
}
# Results
<#
qqqqqqq
#>
```

***Update based on `SilBee's` comment:***

Taking action on any keypress.

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Timer = New-Object system.diagnostics.stopwatch
$Timer.Start()
while ($Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds -le 1000)
{
    $Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey("NoEcho,IncludeKeyDown") | OUT-NULL
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('q')
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100
}
'Done'
$Timer
# Results
<#
Done

IsRunning Elapsed          ElapsedMilliseconds ElapsedTicks
--------- -------          ------------------- ------------
     True 00:00:02.0041171                2004     20041490


 q
#>
```

If you are only after a specific key, then the $Host object still provides that.

```
$Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()
# Results
<#
q
VirtualKeyCode Character ControlKeyState KeyDown
-------------- --------- --------------- -------
            81         q       NumLockOn    True
#>
```

Thus you can code for a specific letter, then branch to whatever other code you choose.

A rough example, could be something like this:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Windows.Forms
$Timer = New-Object system.diagnostics.stopwatch
$Timer.Start()
while (($Host.UI.RawUI.ReadKey()).Character -eq 'q')
{
    [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait('q')
    Start-Sleep -Milliseconds 100

    If ($Timer.ElapsedMilliseconds -ge 5000)
    {Break}
}
'Done'
$Timer
# Results
<#
qqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqqDone

IsRunning Elapsed          ElapsedMilliseconds ElapsedTicks
--------- -------          ------------------- ------------
     True 00:00:05.0420154                5042     50420519
#>
```

Again, the above is a user touching the keyboard, not a simulated event.

Trying to simulate that can/will lead to odd results/behavior with SendKeys, without a lot of fine-tuning and involving potentially calls to user32.dll.

It must be remembered, that press and hold is a mechanical action of the keyboard device (signal to the OS via the keyboard driver). There is no such thing in memory, which is where all code is fired.

Comment: While i think your answer is helpful, there is one difference between this and the physical action. You are actually simulating x keypresses during a time period, pressing 'q' a number of times during one second. Maybe its possible to send a keydown event, wait 1 second, then send the keyup event. I have no idea how to send keyup/keydown events tho, only how to capture them.

Comment: You can leverage key-down/key-up via the $host, but that is only for one press *** (see my update for your point, and even with that, you are just key-down any key, a 'q' gets sent since that is what one told the code to do) *** , not a continuous hold of a specific key. Yet, since the OP said, they wanted this for one second. that is really not a doable physical thing by a human (u know, we very fallible creatures). That also requires more code as you have to have a listener for that. I am really curious why this use case.

Comment: Great update, wish i could upvote again :)

Comment: No worries.  ***;-}***

Comment: @postanote
You write strange things. "pressing" a key for a period of time means that there are several key down events are fired and if the time is over a key up event. There is no problem for a human to do that physically and there is no problem to emit these events in real programming languages.